# Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out

Tags: github, ssh, vpn, ssh-keys

I'm trying to push my commit to github but it keeps throwing the above error. My internet connection is through a vpn that lets me access a system in Canada and I have cloned the repo to that system.

So far I have not faced any issue in performing the same until recently they replaced their old cluser (Mordor) with a new one (Valinor). I suspect this might have cause somethign weird to happen with the SSN keys maybe?

I tried running `ssh -vT git@github.com` and the following came out:

```
(base) [t114244uhn@valinorlogin1 cnvway]$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 62: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22 github.com
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 90236
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I dont understand why it says this:

```
debug1: identity file /mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

Because `/mnt/work1/users/home2/t114244uhn/.ssh/id_rsa` does exist.

There is no firewall/proxy hinderance. I also tried increasing the timeout limit to 300 which still went in vain.

Comment: This isn't programming or development, but the `key_load_public` error applies to the identityfile in the _next_ line; `id_rsa` exists but `id_rsa-cert` and both plain and cert versions of `id_dsa id_ecdsa id_ed25519` do not, which is why they (all) say `type -1`. Anyway your system is apparently configured to use `sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy` and that is exiting for some reason, possibly an error, but we don't know what. If you don't actually need that proxy, and for a public site you probably don't, try temporarily removing it. Keys are not the problem.

Comment: Tried using `env -u SSS_SSH_KNOWNHOSTSPROXY ssh -Tv git@github.com` and got the same output.

Comment: `ssh` isn't configured with environment variables, but commandline options and up to two files: a system file and a per-user file. Your log shows use of the system file but not a per-user file, which is why I said "your system is apparently configured". Either change the setting in the system file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or override it by specifying on the commandline `ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=' ...` .

Comment: Tried `ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=' git@github.com`. Got `write: Broken pipe`.

Comment: Sorry, the option parsing here is more complicated than I realized; it must be `-o 'ProxyCommand=none'` (with or without the quotes; _some_ `-o` options need quoting, so I do it habitually, but this one can do without)

Comment: My administrator finally replied; apparently, the new system I was on (because of the cluster change) is not configured to allow an internet connection and said something about it needing cert updates. I'll just be pushing the commits from my local computer until then.

Thanks a bunch for your help!!